# Can the help center have a list of good places to ask good questions that are not suitable for Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: feature-request, help-center, opinion-based

The last two questions I asked have been downvoted and one of them closed. (I had thought that they were good questions, but it turns out that questions about proper style/conventions are often too opinion based in their answers.)

I feel it's important that I get answers to those questions, because I am tutoring some students and don't want to teach them bad practices. That is why I came to Stack Overflow to ask them.

I was assured by a commenter that my first question (of the two) was not a stupid question, but instead just not a good one for Stack Overflow, because of having too many different answers based on opinion.

I think it would be good if the help center had a list of good places on the Web (i.e., non-Stack Exchange websites) to ask questions not good for Stack Overflow nor for other places on Stack Exchange. I imagine it would make it less tempting to ask such questions on Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange itself.

Comment: Looks like a good idea at first, but Alexei's worry about us sending lots of bad questions to smaller places that may not be equipped to deal with the flood is probably justified.

Comment: I wonder why this get downvoted? It's a nice question. It seems as if people downvote this as they disagree, which is a misuse of the voting buttons.

Answer (score 5):

No.

For the same reason there is no migration to most other SE sites - most people don't know rules on those destinations and hence will result in random posts being sent to such sites.

Note that there are topics on meta for suggestions for many types of questions- in each particular case there is likely answer... But combing them in one list is not practical.

Answer (score 4):

The help center already provides a few suggestions, for instance, at [*What topics can I ask about here?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). More broadly, there is all of [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/) for you to explore. Be sure to check whether your question is actually on topic at the site you plan to bring it to. Opinion-based questions, in particular, are frowned upon not only in Stack Overflow but also in several other Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with this. It would be nice to have one or two mod-editable pages in the Help Center for linking to other resources.

On Software Engineering Stack Exchange, [we do maintain a Meta question for related Stack Exchange sites](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8066/i-have-a-question-but-it-may-not-fit-best-on-software-engineering-where-else-c) that is in the meta faq tag and is linked to on our /help/on-topic page. We link to each site's /help/on-topic page and copy a brief snippet from the other site's /help/on-topic page to help users learn the basics of the other site.

However, I'm not sure how well this would scale to a site that is the size of Stack Overflow. Do you limit it to sites that are generic? Or does your list get massive to include communities for each major language and framework (and what defines a major language or framework)?

Perhaps tag wikis or Documentation can be used somehow. I'm not familiar enough with Documentation to understand how it could used, but there are problems with discoverability and searchability of tag wikis.